# On max-width of CSS Media Query

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

[image]

I see the above recommendation for max-width for mobile phone, tabled and screen.
Is that a best practice for max-width settings for different devices? If not or if there are better, what would be that?

Comment: I usually use bootstrap breakpoints: [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/)

Comment: What breakpoints you use is going to depend on your design(s). Some layouts will work fine on different viewport sizes, some will need different layouts for narrow viewports etc. The designer (maybe you??) needs to say what s suitable on what viewport size'. The concept of 'mobile', 'tablet',  'desktop' seems (to me!) completely irrelevant.